# Use natural deduction tree

Tags: logic

> Use a natural deduction tree to prove $(p \rightarrow (q \vee r))\leftrightarrow ((p\rightarrow q) \vee (p \rightarrow r))$.

I know the $I$ and $E$ rules in natural deduction but I don't know how to use them to prove this. Also I don't know how to type a natural deduction tree in this site to show you my approach. Is there any site that can generate natural deduction proof in the same format as van Dalen book?

Comment: Two subproofs one for the left-to-right $\to$ and the other similarly for right-to-left.

Comment: No effort done using the hints?

Comment: If you still do not understand the two answers, maybe you have to re-read the first chapter of van Dalen's textbook...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* for the left-to-right part:

Start with premise: $p \to (q \lor r)$, to be discharged by a final $(\to \text I)$ and assume [a] $p$; then derive $q \lor r$ and use it $(\lor \text E)$.

For the first case: $q$, we get $(p \to q)$ and thus $(p \to q) \lor (p \to r)$ by $(\lor \text I)$.

For the second case: $r$, we get $(p \to q) \lor (p \to r)$ in the same way.

---

In order to write it in tree-form you can copy-paste some example:

$$
\cfrac{[(p \to (q \lor r)]^1 \ \ \ \ p^2 }{(q \lor r)} \ \ (\to \text E) 
$$

Now we need $(\lor \text E)$:

$$
\cfrac{(q \lor r) \quad  q^3 \vdash (p \to q) \vdash (p \to q) \lor (p \to r) \quad  r^4 \vdash \ldots }{(p \to q) \lor (p \to r)} \ \ (\lor \text E)_{3,4}
$$

---

---

The right-to-left part is quite similar: assume the RHS as premise and assume $p$.Then use the pair $(\lor \text E), (\lor \text I)$ to derive $(q \lor r)$.

Answer (score 1):

Right-to-left:
$$
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac
{
(p\rightarrow q) \vee (p \rightarrow r)
\quad
  \dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad p\rightarrow q}{q}}{q \lor r}
\quad
  \dfrac{\dfrac{p \quad p\rightarrow r}{r}}{q \lor r}
}
{
q \lor r
}
}
{
p \rightarrow (q \vee r)
}
}
{
((p\rightarrow q) \vee (p \rightarrow r)) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (q \vee r))
}
$$